# tornado memory leaks when serve html5 page with <video>

Tags: python, html, memory, memory-leaks, tornado

I was writing a static file server with tornado, but memory leaks when it serves html5 videos, the code is pretty simple.

**server.py**

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '.'}),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**video.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<video src="demo.mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

**Details:**

1. when the html page was loaded, python.exe's memory goes up.
2. If reload the page, memory goes up again ( + 5MB for every reload in my situation )
3. when reloading, an error was raised by tornado ( see the last part )
4. If I play the video, I can see the memory is going down during playing (but always higher than last reload)

**How can I prevent the memory leak ?** 
Thanks!

```
WARNING:tornado.general:error on read
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PROJECTS\Working\PyF5\tornado\iostream.py", line 391, in _handle_read
    if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
  File "D:\PROJECTS\Working\PyF5\tornado\iostream.py", line 447, in _read_to_buffer
    chunk = self.read_from_fd()
  File "D:\PROJECTS\Working\PyF5\tornado\iostream.py", line 683, in read_from_fd
    chunk = self.socket.recv(self.read_chunk_size)
error: [Errno 10053]
```